# Error creating Job: googleapi: Error 403: lacks IAM permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-scheduler

I am getting the following error at the moment to deploy this Cloud Scheduler resource on my dev environment.

```
1. Step #1 - "Terraform plan": │ Error: Error creating Job: googleapi:
    Error 403: The principal (user or service account) lacks IAM
    permission "cloudscheduler.jobs.create" for the resource
    "projects/whg-dev/locations/us-east1" (or the resource may not
    exist).
        
        Step #1 - "Terraform plan": │ 
        
        Step #1 - "Terraform plan": │   with google_cloud_scheduler_job.scheduler,
        
        Step #1 - "Terraform plan": │   on scheduler_template.tf line 11, in resource "google_cloud_scheduler_job" "scheduler":
        
        Step #1 - "Terraform plan": │   11: resource "google_cloud_scheduler_job" "scheduler" {
        
        Step #1 - "Terraform plan": │
```

find below my TF configuration, i could not find what is missing...

```
# Google-Cloud-Scheduler

resource "google_project_service" "scheduler_api" {
  service            = "cloudscheduler.googleapis.com"
  provider           = google-beta
  project            = var.project_id
  disable_on_destroy = false
}


resource "google_cloud_scheduler_job" "scheduler" {
  name               = "NotificationsRemindersBatch-test"
  description        = "test http job"
  schedule           = "*/30 * * * *"
  time_zone          = "Etc/UTC"
  region             = "us-east1"
  attempt_deadline   = "180s"
  project            = var.project_id
  depends_on         = [google_project_service.scheduler_api]

  retry_config {
    retry_count = 1
  }

  http_target {
    http_method      = "POST"
    uri              = "https://notifications-reminders-service-v35463ja-ue.a.run.app/"
    body             = base64encode("{\"foo\":\"bar\"}")
  }
}
```

IAM ROLES config and Authorize

These config are setting in a different repository as main.tf, and this is the setup:

```
resource "google_cloud_run_service_iam_member" "authorize" {
  location = google_cloud_run_service.main.location
  project  = google_cloud_run_service.main.project
  service  = google_cloud_run_service.main.name
  role     = "roles/run.invoker"
  member   = "allUsers"
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "project" {
    count   = length(var.roles)
  project = google_cloud_run_service.main.project
  role    = var.roles[count.index]
  member  = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.sa.email}"
}
```

And in the variable folder there is a "roles" paramater created as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The identity that you used to authorize Terraform does not have the permission **cloudscheduler.jobs.create**. Edit your question and show how you have set up Terraform authorization and the IAM roles that the identity has.

Comment: Your edit does not answer any of my questions. You added the IAM section for Cloud Run and not the identity that you are running Terraform as.

Comment: sorry i dont understand what you are saying :( , first the "cloudscheduler.jobs.create is a permission assigned in this case to "roles/cloudscheduler.admin". As far as understand i have to configure this to avoid this issue, right? am trying to configure this isolated from the rest, just as template configuration.

Comment: By what method did you authorize the Terraform command? Examples, specifying a service account, gcloud application-default login, an environment variable, etc. You must setup Terraform to be able to access your project. If this does not make sense to you, read the documentation on how to get started with Terraform on Google Cloud.

Comment: I found the corresponding service account, and yes you right, i had to assign the cloudscheduler.admin role, after that everything was OK! Thanks John for your approach!

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @John Hanley, you can add a [service account](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/getting_started#adding-credentials) in order to make a request to GCP API.

> In order to make requests against the GCP API, you need to authenticate to prove that it's you making the request.

In addition, I managed to replicate your error and I successfully resolved it by creating a service account containing the `Cloud Scheduler Admin` role. You can follow the official docs on how to [create a service account then download the key](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#create_service_account)

Then pass the **service account key** via **environment variable** [like this](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/getting_started#adding-credentials):

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="path/to/service/account"
```

Sample output: [image]